# VBA : copy and paste last row in current region

Tags: vba, excel

My goal:
copy last row in every current region and paste them into A26 region.
So A26 would be the first cell in that new region.
Also switching cell contents.
Notice that content in cell A = cell C in new range,
B->E, C->B, D->D, E->A.
Expected results is in the image below.

Problem in current code:
I wasn't sure how to copy all cells and paste them into respective col.
Instead of getting ONLY each last row highlighted,
some of the current region got last 2 rows highlighted.
Also the current code, only copy last row in the sheet as it was being overwritten in the loop?

[image: expected results]

```
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets        
    If ws.Name = "Master" Then
    For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
            r = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row 'last row
        Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "J")) 'range = last row cells from col A-J
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'highlight that range
        rng.Copy
        ws.Range("A26").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste them all to same sheet A26
    Next rng
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I am still new to vba.   Can anybody shed me some light?

Comment: Could you add bit more context to your code?  Variable declaration code would help

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, Ive added variable declaration in the code.

Comment: I'll need to see the whole Sub because there is more going on - `ws` is (probably) being set in a loop and there must be some code to rearrange the columns after copy/paste.  Take a look at [mcve] for guidance on what to include.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, I've uploaded the full sub code that I run. Would you have a look ? I'm still stucked at rearranging the col, the one I have in the picture is what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> rng.Copy
> ws.Range("A26").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste them all to same sheet A26
> ```

Your code overwrites always the same row. To avoid this you can change the above statements into

```
Dim pasteRow As Long
pasteRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
If pasteRow < 26 Then pasteRow = 26
ws.Cells(pasteRow, "A").Resize(,rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
```

> B->E, C->B, D->D, E->A

To switch cells when copying, you can play around replacing the last line above, i.e.

```
ws.Cells(pasteRow, "E").Value = rng.Cells(1, "B").Value
ws.Cells(pasteRow, "B").Value = rng.Cells(1, "C").Value
ws.Cells(pasteRow, "D").Value = rng.Cells(1, "D").Value
ws.Cells(pasteRow, "A").Value = rng.Cells(1, "A").Value
```

> Instead of getting ONLY each last row highlighted

I couldn't find a reason for that, other than there were actually two areas, for an unknown reason.